# Parse Query skip more than 10,000 results

Tags: parse-platform

I'm running a Parse Query from <kbd>parse4j</kbd> and have the limit for results set at `1000`, and I loop through, incrementing `skip` to get more that a thousand results.

My problem is I have more than `10K` object I need to return and Parse raises an exception for skips greater than `10K`.

```
ParseException [code=154, error=Skips larger than 10000 are not allowed]
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

According to Parse, this is a very common question, and they have a detailed list of options for you to work around this error.

Check it out at [Parse.com - Paging through more than 10,000 results](https://www.parse.com/questions/paging-through-more-than-10000-results)